# How to make an object that walks forward until it hits a wall?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want a character that simply walks forward until it hits a wall, then it does a 180 degree spin and repeats the action.
Making him walk forward is easy, how do I program him hitting the wall?
My current code:

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 5;
    public Vector3 userDirection = Vector3.forward;   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += userDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use colliders and rotate object when collision occurs?

Comment: @bartol44 how do i use colliders in code?

Comment: There are components called colliders (BoxCollider for instance) that detects collision for you. Then in code the methods like OnCollisionEnter will be called, when something related to collisions happens. If you had no idea such thing exists, I advise you to do some tutorial about them, or check out the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use raycast to detect walls and avoid them.

> [Raycast](https://gamedevbeginner.com/raycasts-in-unity-made-easy/) in Unity is a Physics function that projects a Ray into the scene, returning a boolean value if a target was successfully hit

The following code is a simple demenstration of raycast. Distance determine how far you ray is casted and layermask determine which layers ray should detect. Therefore, you must put your walls in a Layer and sit this variable equal to that:

```
    public float distance;
    public LayerMask wallLayerMask;
    public Vector3 userDirection = Vector3.forward;   

    void Update()
    {
       if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, userDirection, distance, wallLayerMask))
        {
            // rotate, possibly:
            // userDirection *= -1
        }
      transform.position += userDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

***UPDATE***

As stated in comments, you can also use colliders. To use colliders, you need to add another empty gameObject to your enemy, add a SphereCollider to it. Sphere Collider's radius determines how far you want to detect walls. Then add the following code to the second object:

```
    // a reference to your enemy controller class
    public Enemy enemy;
    
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collider other)
    {
        enemy.Rotate();
    }
```

The OnCollisionEnter is called whenever an object, which has a collider, collides with our object. You need to assign a layer to this new object (wallCheck) and another to your walls. Then from Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics uncheck the collision of wallCheck with any layer other than your walls layer.

Comment: While this works perfectly fine, using raycasts instead of collision in this case seems like a huge overkill. Also OP seems to be not aware of colliders at all, so you are distracting him with less obvious solution, while he still needs to learn the basics. If all that still isn't convincing, using simple Vector3.Distance is going to do the job as well, it's faster, and you still would need to measure distance from your ray hit anyway.

Comment: To use distance he needs a reference for walls. Then each time he adds a wall he needs to assign it to the script. If you want to use collisionEnter, then you have to check it with a layer, what raycast does for you. Moreover, there are possibly other objects in the way, so the collisionEnter keeps being called, so why not using raycast? you don't need to measuse distance, the ray is casted that far

Comment: I can agree with a part about references, with just distance, you would need to iterate over all walls, which seems bad (unless there are just two of them, as agent is going back and forth in this case.) If there are more objects in the way, you can use layer collision matrix, just as easy as you provide layer mask to your raycast. Still for me it's so bizarre to use raycasts for this issue. You want to do thing when you touch something, that's a perfect use case for colliders.

Comment: With this logic, you could not use colliders at all, and use raycasts for everything, and there's question back to you: why? :P Guess in the end, the performance is what matters, and if you end up with raycasts being more efficient, that would be the only reason I would use them in this case.

Comment: Yes, using layer collision is a way, but whenever you add a new layer, you must update your matrix. Next, imagine you want to detect wall within 3 meters distance, you possibly need a box or sphere collider of that size, then it would collide with everything and you have to update matrix again. then you add a new object with a new layer, and a new update. I think it's easier to say what you should do rather than what you shouldn't do

Comment: this is a thread about collider and raycast: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-physics-colliders-or-raycast.631159/

Comment: with what logic you can use raycasts all the time? how did you deduce that?

Comment: I deduced it from your question, 'why not use raycasts?' I could ask this question to any collision issue, and still get away with 'yeah, it doesn't seem best, but until I got performance results, I can use either technique'. I probably exaggerated a bit too much, though :P. Imo we should end here, as it seems we are arguing over personal preference: for me, it's natural to use colliders and collision matrix, for you, it poses problems with updating it every time you add something. In the end, you should know both solutions, and apply them when needed, prioritizing performance.

Comment: I'll add your solution to my answer so people use any solution they wish.